# Find corners in SVG path

Tags: javascript, svg

I need to break a path made only of straight segments into an array of corner points.

My input looks for example like this:

```
M447,390h-24l26.77686,-18.11376c0.40304,3.41283 0.66687,6.74013 0.77624,9.94164z
```

or graphically like this:

[image]

I managed to convert the d attribute into a series of commands with [parse-svg-path](https://github.com/jkroso/parse-svg-path) resulting in this:

```
[ 
  ["M", 447, 390],
  ["h", -24],
  ["l", 26.77686, -18.11376],
  ["c", 0.40304, 3.41283, 0.66687, 6.74013, 0.77624, 9.94164],
  ["z"]
]
```

How should I go about converting this to a series of 4 corner points coordinates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may convert this `["M", 447, 390]` to `{x:447,y:390}`

You may convert this `["h", -24]` to `{x:447-24,y:390}`.

Explanation: `h` is an horizontal line. Since the command is lowercase the coordinates are relatives to the previous point and since it's an horizontal line the `y` coordinate is the same as the last point's `y`

You may convert this `["l", 26.77686, -18.11376]` to `{x:447-24+26.77686,y:390-18.11376}` 
Explanation: `l` is a line and since the command is lowercase the coordinates are relatives to the previous point

this: `["c", 0.40304, 3.41283, 0.66687, 6.74013, 0.77624, 9.94164]` is a cubic Bézier but if you need just a point you can take the last 2 digits and the point is: `{x:447-24+26.77686+0.77624,y:390-18.11376+9.94164}` 
Exactly as before c is a lowercase command and the coordinates are relatives to the previous point

this `["z"]` tells you that the path is closed and you can use again the first point `{x:447,y:390}`

And this is is an example where I use those points to draw small circles:

```html
<svg viewBox="421 371 31 20" width="300">
<path d="M447,390h-24l26.77686,-18.11376c0.40304,3.41283 0.66687,6.74013 0.77624,9.94164z"  />


<circle fill="red" cx="447" cy="390" r=".5" />
<circle fill="red" cx="423" cy="390" r=".5" />                      
<circle fill="red" cx="449.77686" cy="371.88624" r=".5" />             
<circle fill="red" cx="450.5531" cy="381.82788" r=".5" />            
                 
  
</svg>
```